# LibGDX: Sprites not showing on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx

On Samsung S6, sprites are not being shown (textures of the UI skin are).

However, everything works fine in the Desktop application, and on another phone (Samsung S3 Mini).

My images are sized in power-of-two, and have no bigger resolutions than 512x512.

Why does it not work on S6? How can I make it work?

**How I load images:**

I have many textures and I load them with AssetManager, like so:

```
manager.load(STRING_PATH_1, Texture.class, paramBG);
manager.load(STRING_PATH_2, Texture.class, paramBG);
```

**How I draw images:**
I draw them as `Sprite` objects:

```
sprite = new Sprite(Assets.manager.get(Assets.BTN_START, Texture.class));
sprite.setPosition(x, y);
sprite.setSize(radius * 2, radius * 2);
```

In `render()`:

```
sprite.draw(batch);
```

**How I dispose images:**
I do not do that yet, because I am lazy, I want to handle that a little bit later. (Please tell me if this could be relevant for that problem!)

Comment: with so little info no one can help you any further. Post the android code

Comment: @george Which part of the code should I post? (I do not have any specific Android code, only AndroidLauncher, but there I do not do any things for textures.)

Comment: How are you loading, drawing and disposing images?

Comment: @MennoGouw I've edited the question

Comment: `AssetManager` should not be static. I know a lot of sources do this but the official docs recommend against this. Just load your assets with the`AssetManager` and pass it along where you need it.

Comment: @MennoGouw Sorry, I think I don't understand you correctly, could you please explain it a little bit more? Why is it not recommended for `AssetManager` to be static? And what do you mean by "Just load your assets with theAssetManager and pass it along where you need it."?

Comment: Read: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager and since it's not static anymore you cannot access it from wherever you like so you have to pass it along with other objects to use it.

Comment: Alright, thank you!